# UITextFieldProblem

Tags: iphone, navigation

I have one issue with UITextField

In my first view there are two things a UITextField and a UIButton.
Now when I click on button then the value of the textfield must be displayed on the label which is in secondview controller.

Please help.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem...

Comment: The question is not clear still i am integrating the question the way i understood..
What sudha means to say is sudha has one textfield and button in firstview when sudha enter the text in the textfield and clicks the button it should open the second view which has label and the value on the previous view must get displayed on the label. Am i right sudha?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for this One of them is take a string in the appDelegate file
NSString * myString;

set its property and synthesis it..

Then on click event of the button in first view set the value of string to the value of textField i.e. appDelegate.myString=textField.text;

In the second view assign the value of string to the label:
label.text=appDelegate.myString......

Hope this helps...

Happy Coding